# Returning SUM, ignoring column duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 columns in a Google Sheet

> C = order number

> N = shipping cost

If a customer order has more than one line item, the order number & shipping cost are listed twice -- but I just need to sum the "unique" shipping cost, ignoring the duplicate line entries

| COLUMN C | COLUMN N |
| --- | --- |
| Order1 | £10.00 |
| Order1 | £10.00 |
| Order1 | £10.00 |
| Order2 | £5.00 |
| Order3 | £5.00 |

My expected result from the sample above would be £20.00.
Order 1 was £10 postage, Order 2 was £5, Order 3 was £5.

I can get this to work using `=UNIQUE(C3:C)` in a helper column then doing `VLOOKUP(N1, C3:N, 12, FALSE)` -- then summing that but I was hoping to have one formula in one cell (C1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula that should work for you:

`=sum(iferror(arrayformula(VLOOKUP(unique($C$3:$C), $C$3:$N, 12, 0))))`

You had all the pieces, they just needed to be put together.

[image: ex]

Please let me know if you have any issues with this

Comment: Incredible Kaitlyn -- thanks so much. Now I will research that (iferror too! :)